# Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubyxl

I wanna export xlsx excel file using ruby in ROR so i'm install rubyXL. i use this command:
sudo gem install rubyXL  --source http://rubygems.org and then it have error like below

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rubyXL' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Please help me

Comment: I think you need to use HTTPS instead of HTTP...

Comment: i already use https but still error

Answer (score 6):

Disabling ipv6 solved the issue for me:

https://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/ubuntu-disable-ipv6/

Comment: I was having this issue on mac and this worked for me, I used the Terminal to disable ipv6 temporarily:  **Disable** `networksetup -setv6off Ethernet && networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi` - **Enable**: `networksetup -setv6automatic Wi-Fi && networksetup -setv6automatic Ethernet`

Answer (score 3):

Specify the source with the command,

```
    gem install <gem_name> --source http://rubygems.org
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update rubygems and try again.

```
gem update --system
```

Answer (score -1):

Rebooting my laptop solved the issue for me.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33846486)